# как использовать @use c переменными в sass/scss файле?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, scss, импорт

Есть файл:

```
// _variables.scss
// COLORS
    $dark-gray: #222222;
```

который я помещаю в:

```
// index.scss
   @use  './modules/variables' as v;
   div{
      background: v.$dark_gray;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
   }
```

Следуя документации SASS.

Компилятор не видит переменные v.$dark_gray а просто $dark_gray тоже не работает.
Пробовал @use  './modules/variables' as *; но тоже никакого толку.

С @import это работает как часы, но по какой-то причине команда SASS посчитала что это неправильно и перешла на неизвестный @use нормальной информации по которой я нигде не нашел.

Я пробовал с @forward в другом файле forward.scss и его вписывал в index.scss @use 'forward'.

Как мне использовать только переменные в index.scss без @import?

Пишу самую обычную страничку без nodejs и других фреймворков в VScode. Может это из-за старого live sass compiler в VScode?
Мне просто нужно чтобы index.scss видел переменные и все.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в старом Live sass compiler в vscode.
Прости команда SASS.